# Nsurl returns nil when unwrapping

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
var Baseurl = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"   
Baseurl = Baseurl+"lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude

var url = NSURL(string: Baseurl)!
println(url)
```

When i run the code i get the following error:

> unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value.

How is this possible? Baseurl contains a full string when you print it, but when you print url you get the error.

Comment: maybe removing the `!` in `var url = NSURL(string: Baseurl)!`. What is Baseurl value before the `NSURL` call?

Comment: The problem is likely within `Baseurl`, but we cannot comment without seeing that. For example, do you have a `?` after the base URL and before your parameters? Look at what the final `Baseurl` is before you convert it to a `NSURL` and the problem(s) will undoubtedly jump out at you.

Comment: @rob i have added the baseurl

Comment: You're missing the `http://` at the start. Also, I'd suggest looking at it after adding the latitude and longitude, right before you convert it to a `NSURL`, in case there's anything curious in those parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL requires a scheme, the `http://`, at the start of the URL string.

Answer (score 0):

`NSURL(string : String)` must start with a valid scheme like `http://`, `ftp://`